# How to authenticate username and password in Inno Setup by reading registry

Tags: inno-setup

I want to authenticate the password from registry.

While installing it should read the password from registry using Inno Setup.

Comment: So do you want a custom page in the installer that will ask for username and password? And once the user enters them, it will compare these against some keys in registry?

Comment: yes it should read after entering the username and password

Comment: OK, what part of the task do you have problem with? The custom page or the registry reading?

Comment: registry reading only i just need to read username and password from registry

Comment: From what registry? Is it some custom registry key of your application? So is your question really as simple as "Read string value from registry?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just see the official example for the [`RegQueryStringValue` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_regquerystringvalue):

```pascal
var
  Country: String;
begin
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Control Panel\International',
     'sCountry', Country) then
  begin
    { Successfully read the value }
    MsgBox('Your country: ' + Country, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```